# MYSQL alias on LEFT join table error

Tags: mysql

can't find the table declared on LEFT join using alias. Here's my query:

```
    "INSERT INTO currentweekvalue (symbol,value)
                        SELECT * FROM(SELECT cwv.symbol AS csymbol, (cwv.value + di.value) AS totval
                            FROM currentweekvalue  AS cwv
                            LEFT JOIN $dayiterated  AS di
                            ON cwv.symbol = di.symbol) cmbtbl
                        WHERE cmbtbl.csymbol =  cmbtbl.di.symbol
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(cmbtbl.totval)";
```

I've encountered Unknown column 'cmbtbl.di.symbol' in 'where clause'. How to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: The `WHERE cmbtbl.csymbol =  cmbtbl.di.symbol` is in the wrong scope, and looks redundant, as though it is mixing the characteristics of an implicit join and explicit left join. The condition it compares is the same condition in the join's `ON`. If you remove that `WHERE` clause, do you get the expected result?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i get an error when i remove where Unknown column 'cmbtbl.totval' in 'field list'. Thanks

Comment: @Beginnerexpert That should probably be `VALUES(value)` - when using a value from the `SELECT`. But it is unclear from the documentation if using `VALUES() in that way is supported with an `INSERT INTO ..SELECT`